# Crystal Report select values after generating report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have got an sql database and want to report the data with crystal report. the problem is, that one field is generating after the report is created. so i cannot ask in the sql statement

```
select * from table where status like available;
```

I have this code in formularfield with an IF ELSE statement. How can i create a final report after generating this current report?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Something is not clear about the lifecycle you're talking about. can you explain better? 1)report is requested by user 2)query is executed 3)report is created.... then???

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to create views in the SQL database, you could create a view that you'll use as virtual look-up table for the values you want to select.  Alternatively, you could build and insert a sub-report that generates that list of values you want and then link it back (or use a Shared variable) to use it in the main report.